# Logic gate summary / explanation

Tags: logic-gates

Is there any place (or book) where all the basic logic gates and their applications (including adders, half adders, multiplexers, demultiplexers, bit counters, flip flops, etc) are fully explained? This is the subject sometimes called "combinatorial logic".

Just to be clear here I am not interested in TTL components here; I just want to know the logic. In other words I do not explanations of PN junctions etc etc.

I keep seeing "lectures" that describe a few logic gate schematics here, a few circuits there, but do not comprehensively describe every logic gate and every simple machine (adders etc). For example, if you do a book search on "combinatorial logic" on Amazon you will find there are no books at all on the subject.

Comment: Have you tried the datasheets of the devices in question?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The question is not about devices, it is about logic.

Comment: You can look for books on "digital electronics".

Comment: @RogerC. I have Hill & Horowitz and also many other books. The problem is that these books are on ELECTRONICS not logic, so their discussions of combinatorial logic gates is always lacking and incomplete. They introduce a few gates, then immediately go into mapping and then other topics that have nothing to do with logic.

Comment: Perhaps you would have more luck searching for information on "Boolean Algebra" rather than "Logic Gates". The former is the principles used, the latter are electronic structures.

Comment: Your question might not be about actual devices, but many manufacturers provide a logic-gate level diagram of the internals in their data sheets of the more complex digital functions. If you wanted a book, the subject matter would probably be "Digital Logic" or "TTL Logic" - again, using that series of chips as a context. The combinatorial vs. registered distinction tends to see more attention in academic settings or in the context of FPGAs where building complex systems is practical. Most simple intro books cover both as the TTL ICs that are their context of practicality include some of both.

Answer (score 2):

Try "Experiments in Digital Principles" by Donald P. Leach. I think it will answer most of your questions.

From the table of contents:

- Logic invertor
- or, and, nor and nand gates
- boolean algebra
- 4-input multiplexer
- 1-of-4 decoder
- bcd to decimal decoder
- xor gates
- adders
- multiplexers adder-substracter
- flip-flops
- shift registers
- counters

And many more interesting subjects.

Comment: That looks like it might be a good resource, but I could not find that book for sale either on Amazon or ABE Books, so how would I get it?

Comment: Googling the book title immediately shows it is available on Amazon for as little s 20 cents.

Comment: I think I did not find it the first time because you mispelled the title and I copied and pasted it.

Comment: **principal** prɪnsɪp(ə)l _adjective_: first in order of importance; main. **principle** prɪnsɪp(ə)l _noun_: a general scientific theorem or law that has numerous special applications across a wide field. Spelling matters! Edit required!

Comment: @transistor Yes, I corrected the title. I did a search on Amazon before posting my answer (it would be pointless to promote a book that's unavailable) but then typed it wrong here. It happens.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for the contents of *any* basic book about digital electronics design. Seriously, you can pick any one of them.

But allow me to suggest **Structured Computer Organization** by **Andrew Tanenbaum**. While not being a book about digital circuit design (it is actually a book about how computers work, from bare-metal hardware to assembly language), it contains a *very* clear explanation of the basics of digital logic.

Comment: That book does not discuss combinatorial boolean logic.

Comment: Actually, it does, even if in a basic way (check Chapter 3). Perhaps you're looking for something more advanced (ASIC design oriented). In that case SCO is certainly not enough.

Comment: As I said in my question, I am interested in comprehensive treatment. See JvO's answer for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend very much

> "Digital Design and Computer Architecrure" by Harris and Harris

It's the best text book on that subject I know.
The first 3 chapters cover quite well what you are looking for:

1. **From Zero to One**
   1.1 The Game Plan
   1.2 The Art of Managing Complexity
   1.3 The Digital Abstraction
   1.4 Number Systems
   1.5 Logic Gates
   1.6 Beneath the Digital Abstraction
   1.7 CMOS Transistors
   1.8 Power Consumption
   1.9 Summary and a Look Ahead, Exercises, Interview Questions
2. **Combinational Logic Design**
   2.1 Introduction
   2.2 Boolean Equations
   2.3 Boolean Algebra
   2.4 From Logic to Gates
   2.5 Multilevel Combinational Logic
   2.6 X’s and Z’s, Oh My
   2.7 Karnaugh Maps
   2.8 Combinational Building Blocks
   2.9 Timing
   2.10 Summary, Exercises, Interview Questions
3. **Sequential Logic Design**
   3.1 Introduction
   3.2 Latches and Flip-Flops
   3.3 Synchronous Logic Design
   3.4 Finite State Machines
   3.5 Timing of Sequential Logic
   3.6 Parallelism
   3.7 Summary, Exercises, Interview Questions

The other chapters are:
 4. **Hardware Description Languages**
 5. **Digital Building Blocks**
 6. **Architecture**
 7. **Microarchitecture**
 8. **Memory Systems**